# JavaFX: Rotated pane in the x-Axis or y-Axis doesn't render completly

Tags: 3d, javafx, scene, pane, javafx-3d

Rotating a Pane around the z-axis (pointing outwards the screen) works just fine, however rotating it around the y-axis or x-axis in a 3D scene doesn't render it completly. For example:

```
BoderPane b = new BorderPane();
b.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(180, Rotate.X_AXIS));
```

I'm trying to display text in bordered panels in a 3D scene. So I would welcome any solution to this problem even if it doesn't involve `Pane` classes.
Like printing text and borders on `Box` shape surfaces. (Text changing dynamically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 8u40, it has been fixed.

This is the sample from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753724/javafx-2d-text-with-background-in-3d-scene/28762212#28762212), adding this rotation:

```
boderPane.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(180, Rotate.X_AXIS));
```

[image: border pane]